# How to reflect line type in legend in canvasjs

Tags: canvasjs

I have a graph of two lines, one of type solid, the other of type dashed, however the legend shows them both as solid. Is there a way to have the dashed line show up in the legend to accurately reflect what line matches what legend data?

[image: graph example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this feature is currently not available, you can workaround this problem by setting legendMarkerType to "triangle" with color same as that of chart background. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/9t4gy30c/).

```
legendMarkerType: "triangle",
legendMarkerColor :"white",
```